# Add bootstrap tooltip to datatable search bar

Tags: razor, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add bootstrap tool-tip to data-table search box, I can't seem to find any help for that
This is what i have tried but it is not working :

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').attr('title', 'Type here to search in the table');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that would work :

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
                             .attr('data-placement', 'top')
                             .attr('title', 'Type here to search in the table')
                             .tooltip();
```

A quick note, Bootstrap 4 depend on Popper.js so you have ton include it to be sure everything will work.
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js

Comment: I have verified that this works.  As mentioned, Popper.js is required too.

Comment: Looking more closely at it, the data toggle and placement attributes seem to be ignored.

Comment: $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('title', 'Type here to search in the table')
                             .tooltip();